# Command line arguments is causing Exception in "main" thread

Tags: java, arrays, command-line-arguments, bubble-sort

```
import java.util.*;

public class bubblesort {
        public int input;
        public int c;
        public int d; 
        public int swap;
        public int[] arr= new int[input];
        Random rand = new Random();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        bubblesort b = new bubblesort();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ascending(1),Descending(2),Random(3)");
        int arrayInput= in.nextInt();

        if (arrayInput == 1) {
            b.ascending(args);
            }
        else if (arrayInput == 2) {
            b.descending(args);
            }   
        else if (arrayInput == 3) {
            b.random(args);
            }           
    }


    public void ascending(String[] args){   
        this.input = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        for (c = 0; c < input; c++){ 
          arr[c] = rand.nextInt(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
          }

        for (c = 0; c < ( input - 1 ); c++) {
            for (d = 0; d < input - c - 1; d++) {
             if (arr[d] > arr[d+1]){
                  swap       = arr[d];
                  arr[d]   = arr[d+1];
                  arr[d+1] = swap;
                }
            }
        } 
        for (c = 0; c < input; c++) 
        System.out.println(arr[c]);

        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        for (c = 0; c < input - 1; c++){
            for (d =0; d < input - c -1 ; d++){
                if (arr[d] > arr[d+1]){
                     swap = arr[d];
                     arr[d] = arr[d+1];
                     arr[d+1] = swap;
                     }
                }
            }
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        long estimatedTime = endTime - startTime;
        System.out.println("Sorted list of numbers");
        for (c = 0; c < input; c++) 
        System.out.println(arr[c]);
        System.out.println("The time it takes to sort an descending array into an ascending array is "+estimatedTime+" nano seconds");
        }
    }
```

So when I compile this file  (this isn't my whole file) it compiles, its just when i try to run it it gives the the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at bubblesort.ascending(bubblesort.java:61)
    at bubblesort.main(bubblesort.java:23)
```

I think the problem is that the array length, or i called it "input" is not changing to the command line argument integer, so input stays at zero. If this is so, how can I fix this problem?

Comment: your didnt assign any value to `input`, so it is 0, and you created array `arr` with length 0. If you wanna use `arr`, you have to assign a value that bigger than your variable `c` and `d`

Comment: Remember to use your IDE's breakpoints and debugging capabilities. It's invaluable to be able to step into your code and look at the length of your arrays when hunting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't initialize `arr` before you parse the user input. The statement `public int[] arr= new int[input];` results with an array of size 0 so any attemt to access it will throw an exception. Try initializing the array inside the main, after parsing the array length.

Answer (score 1):

At the top where you have your variables.

```
public int input; //NOT INITIALIZED
public int[] arr= new int[input];
```

your input is not initialized before you try to create the array. so it has no size.

Try initializing it with the user input inside the main function then create the array.

```
int arrayInput= in.nextInt();
arr = new int[arrayInput];
```